# PostgreSQL server problem in Windows XP

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

```
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-09-30 18:30:24 IST
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 2/12B85678
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  redo is not required
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2014-10-01 09:22:49 IST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2014-10-01 10:46:19 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2014-10-01 10:46:19 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2014-10-01 10:46:19 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2014-10-01 10:47:22 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2014-10-01 11:56:01 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.


2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST WARNING:  column "trdate" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST WARNING:  column "trno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST WARNING:  column "vrno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST WARNING:  column "suppname" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:19:53 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST WARNING:  column "trdate" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST WARNING:  column "trno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST WARNING:  column "vrno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST WARNING:  column "suppname" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:23 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST WARNING:  column "trdate" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST WARNING:  column "trno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST WARNING:  column "vrno" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST WARNING:  column "suppname" has type "unknown"
2014-10-01 12:20:37 IST DETAIL:  Proceeding with relation creation anyway.
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST LOG:  server process (PID 5432) was terminated by exception 0xC0000142
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2014-10-01 12:20:39 IST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2014-10-01 12:20:40 IST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2014-10-01 12:20:40 IST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2014-10-01 12:20:40 IST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2014-10-01 12:20:40 IST FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2014-10-01 12:20:40 IST LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2014-10-01 12:20:50 IST FATAL:  pre-existing shared memory block is still in use
2014-10-01 12:20:50 IST HINT:  Check if there are any old server processes still running, and terminate them.
```

Given above is the `Postgres_Log` (click [here to see full log info](http://pastie.org/9609564)), what can be the reason?

1. No firewalls enabled
2. Version :PostgreSQL 9.2
3. PostgreSQL server installed on Windows XP
4. Clients are connecting via LAN

Comment: A PostgreSQL backend is crashing, perhaps in response to a query. Set `log_min_messages = debug1` and `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf`.  Do you have any PostgreSQL addons or extensions installed/loaded? (`0xC0000142` means `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`). Also, what's the *exact* PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @CraigRinger `PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit`

Comment: @CraigRinger BTW,No add-on installed except `PostgreSQL`

Comment: Restart Pg and see if it crashes again, or do whatever you need to do to make it crash. then upload a new log.

Comment: @CraigRinger log generated after the changes in `postgresql.conf` editing see [here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/22fn5t5z973ppkc/postgresql-2014-10-06_141611.log)

Answer (score 1):

In point 4 you say something about clients connecting from the network, not from the box itself. By default, PostgreSQL remote access is disabled for security reasons, see:

[How Do I Enable remote access to PostgreSQL database server?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)

That suggests you:

1. Login over ssh if server is outside your IDC
2. Enable client authentication
3. Enable networking for PostgreSQL
4. Allow TCP/IP socket
5. Restart PostgreSQL
6. Set Iptables firewall rules